# Trouble retrieving inner text from XML node using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm reading an XML document using JavaScript & jQuery, and need to extract some text from inside a node to save into an array. The structure of the XML is as such:

```
<C>
  <I>
    <TEXTFORMAT>
      <P>
        <FONT>Here's the text I want</FONT>
      </P>
    </TEXTFORMAT>
  </I>
</C>
```

Everything I've tried so far returns nothing so I must be incorrectly referencing the contents of the FONT tag.

What XML path should I be using?

Comment: Does `$(xml).find('TEXTFORMAT P FONT').text()` not work?

Comment: That does work, however it retrieves the content of every FONT tag in the XML, I need it to only retrieve the content of the node it's currently looking at. What should I change?

Comment: <FONT>? ouch. What have you tried? sounds like $("font") would work fine in this situation.

Comment: What does *"the content of the node it's currently looking at"* mean? What is *it* and why is it staring at your nodes?

Comment: Maybe I have explained badly.

My XML file contains a number of <C> nodes as shown above, all with the same nodes inside them. I'm trying to extract the inner text of each <C> node one at a time to save them individually into an array.

Comment: @JackRoscoe - if you are already working on pieces of the XML document, you can use jQuery to work on those pieces too, rather than the entire document. So instead of `$(myEntireXmlDoc).find(...)`, do `$(theContentIAmLookingAt).find(...)`. Also, if you are already working on a raw XML object, you should be able to drill down to the text like this: `theXmlIAmLookingAt.getElementsByTagName('font')[0].firstChild.nodeValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you an array of the content of the `FONT` nodes.

```
var array = $(xml).find('FONT').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

---

**Relevant jQuery docs:**

- `.map()` - http://api.jquery.com/map/
- `.text()` - http://api.jquery.com/text/
- `.get()` - http://api.jquery.com/get/
- `.find()` - http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseXml(xml)
{
    //find every FONT element and store its value
    $(xml).find("FONT").each(function()
    {
        // put this.text() into the array
    });

}
```